# Update for Mobile Intel 4 series chipset family won't work for my VAIO CS (can't get OpenGL 2.0 to work)

Tags: laptop, drivers, opengl, intel-graphics

I've installed a program that requires me to run OpenGL 2.0. I've bough my laptop in 2009 and OpenGL 2.0 was released in 2004 so I figure there has to be a way to get OpenGL 2.0 to work. (Current OpenGL version is 1.5).

**My CPU is:** Intel Mobile Core 2 Duo T5800
**My graphics card is:** Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset.
**My laptop is:** SONY VAIO CS-190E running Windows Vista 32.

I go to VAIO support and obv my driver (released in 2008) is up to date and they have no newer version.

I go to Intel: [Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Drivers page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Laptop%20graphics%20drivers&ProductProduct=Mobile%20Intel%C2%AE%204%20Series%20Express%20Chipset%20Family&ProdId=2991&LineId=1101&FamilyId=39). I select my OS and the latest .exe for the driver. Download the driver. And in the description before the install my processor isn't listed. OK so I continue with the installation anyway (don't tell me it's not recommended) and I get the message that it won't install and I need to get the driver from my manufacturer.

Catch 22 or what?

**Can someone, please, help me get OpenGL 2.0 to work on my laptop?**

Comment: What driver version do you currently have installed?

Comment: The version of the driver is: 7.15.10.1511